# Service not starting jar via SH script

Tags: shell-script, services

I'm trying to run a shell script via a service. This seems to be working fine and the service is able to call the shell script. The issue is when the wiremock_process.sh is called via the service, it believes that the process is already running. However if I run "ps -ef | grep wiremock | grep -v grep" this is not true. I'm also able to run my shell script and start it just fine without the service

Any help would be appreciated!

journal

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-10-08 14:43:49 EDT, end at Thu 2020-10-08 14:44:59 EDT. --
Oct 08 14:44:57 vc2coma1313056n systemd[1]: Started Service to start wiremock.
Oct 08 14:44:57 vc2coma1313056n bash[2836]: Wiremock is already running. Please stop the process and try
Oct 08 14:44:57 vc2coma1313056n systemd[1]: wiremock.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1
Oct 08 14:44:57 vc2coma1313056n systemd[1]: Unit wiremock.service entered failed state.
Oct 08 14:44:57 vc2coma1313056n systemd[1]: wiremock.service failed.
```

**wiremock.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Service to start wiremock

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "source /apps/wiremock/wiremock_process.sh && wiremock_start"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**wiremock_process.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
#Script to start/stop wiremock process
#Date 08-OCT-2020
wiremock_start()
{
        ## Don't start if wiremock is already running
        if [[ `ps -ef | grep wiremock | grep -v grep | wc -l` -ne 0 ]]; then
                echo "Wiremock is already running. Please stop the process and try again"
                exit 1;
        fi

    echo 'Starting...' 
        ##Start the process
        
        java -jar /apps/wiremock/wiremock-standalone-2.27.0.jar --port 9999 --global-response-templating &

}

wiremock_stop()
{
        ## Check if the  wiremock is stopped
        if [[ `ps -ef | grep wiremock | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 0 ]]; then
                echo "wiremock is not running. Please start the process and try again"
                exit 1;
        fi

        PID=$(ps -ef | grep wiremock | grep java | awk '{print $2}')

        kill $PID

        echo "Done"

}
```

Comment: You might want to read this: https://jdebp.eu/FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing  `if [[` ps -ef | grep wiremock | grep -v grep | wc
-l `-ne 0 ]]; then`

to `if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 )) then`

Comment: this leads to echo "starting..." but i dont see my jar running

Comment: Oct 09 10:15:56 abc systemd[1]: Started Service to start wiremock.
Oct 09 10:15:56 abc bash[13020]: Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Oct 09 10:15:56 abc bash[13020]: Try 'grep --help' for more information.
Oct 09 10:15:56 abc bash[13020]: Starting...